# My attempt to delete a line in a text file is leaving a return carriage

Tags: c++

In the below function I create a key then search for it in the input file. The function outputs each line it reads unless it matches the key.

The function seems to work except that after it copies the last record the `endl` leaves a carriage return on the text file. When I then read the file it reads the last line twice because of the return.

I tried using a space and that does the exact same thing. Is there a way that after the while statement runs I can delete that last space or return? or can I otherwise avoid writing the space or return on the last record?

```
void deleteAddress(){
  ifstream infile( "addressbook.txt", ios::in);
  ofstream outfile ("ACopy.txt", ios::out);

  string last, first, address1, address2, address3, address4;
  string address5, address6, bday, anniversary, delL, delF;
  int key, keyDel;

  cout<<"Enter the name of the the client you want to delete (format: last, first)"<<endl;
  cin>> delL >> delF;

  keyDel = createKey(delL,delF);

  while(! infile.eof()) {
    (infile >> last >> first >> address1 >> address2 >> 
               address3 >> address4 >> address5 >> address6 >>
               bday >> anniversary);

    key = createKey(last, first);

    if(key != keyDel) {
      outfile << last << " "<<first << " "<<address1 << " " <<
                 address2 << " "<<address3 << " "<<address4 << 
                 " "<<address5 << " "<<address6 << " "<<bday <<
                 " "<<anniversary<<endl;
    }
  }
  outfile.close();
  infile.close();
}
```

Below is the display function (`displauCopy`) and `createKey` I am using:

```
void displayCopy(){
    string line;
    string last, first, address1, address2, address3;
    string address4, address5, address6, bday, anniversary;
    ifstream infile("ACopy.txt");

    cout<<"First" << std::setfill(' ')<<setw(15) << "Last" <<endl;

    while(! infile.eof())
    {
        (infile >> last >> first >> address1 >> address2 >>
                   address3 >> address4 >> address5 >> address6 >>
                   bday >> anniversary);

        cout<< last <<", "<<first<<" "<<address1<<" "
        <<address2<<" "<<address3<<", "<<address4<<", "
        <<address5<<" "<<address6<<" "<<bday<<" "<<anniversary<<endl;
    }
    infile.close();
}

int createKey (string first, string last) {
    int key; 
    key = (int)last[0]+(int)last[1]+(int)last[2]+(int)first[0];
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide source code of `createKey` method and example of line from `addressbook.txt` for which your program failed?

Comment: int createKey(string first, string last)
    {
        int key;
        key = (int)last[0]+(int)last[1]+(int)last[2]+(int)first[0];
        return key;
    }

Comment: If you are sure that all last names has at least 3 characters you should use short `addressbook.txt` (with 2 or 3 records), set a break point to `if(key != keyDel)` statement and check values

Comment: yeah I know the key has issues, the printing was just the more pressing matter atm, will fix that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you're looping on EOF-test, which is a bad idea.

You don't even check whether your input succeeded, and so even when it fails (because the stream didn't error, but there's nothing left in it), you will still output something.  And because those strings are scoped outside the loop, they contain whatever the last iteration put in them.

Instead of looping on EOF-test, you could make this small modification:

```
while( infile >> last >> first >> address1 >> address2 >> address3
              >> address4 >> address5 >> address6 >> bday >> anniversary )
{
    cout<< last <<", "<<first<<" "<<address1<<" "
        <<address2<<" "<<address3<<", "<<address4<<", "
        <<address5<<" "<<address6<<" "<<bday<<" "<<anniversary<<endl;
}
```

Alternatively, if everything is on a single line, you can use `std::getline` and then read out of a string stream:

```
int line_num = 0;
string line;
while( getline( infile, line ) )
{
    ++linenum;
    istringstream iss( line );

    if( iss >> last >> first >> address1 >> address2 >> address3
            >> address4 >> address5 >> address6 >> bday >> anniversary )
    {
        cout<< last <<", "<<first<<" "<<address1<<" "
            <<address2<<" "<<address3<<", "<<address4<<", "
            <<address5<<" "<<address6<<" "<<bday<<" "<<anniversary<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error reading line " line_num << " : " << line << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably should have been specific, but you should follow either of these patterns for _all_ your file input, not just the "display" function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figured it a way around this problem, figures I work for 2 hours trying to fix this and I figure it out 5 minutes after posting

```
void displayCopy2()
{
ifstream infile( "ACopy.txt", ios::in);         


char readLetter;
char ch;

  while((ch = infile.get()) != EOF)            
{
    cout<<ch;                
}
}
```